# Unable to access child component after using $A.createComponent

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I have a series of screens, each screen is a lightning component, dependant on the answers you go to different screens. I an loading the screens dynamically.

I am using this code to dynamically inject custom Lightning components.

```
injectComponent: function (cmp, name) {

    var self = this;
    var activeScreen = cmp.find('activeScreen');

    if (activeScreen) {
        activeScreen.destroy();
    }

    var target = cmp.find('main');

    $A.createComponent(name, {
        "aura:id": "activeScreen"
    }, function (contentComponent, status, error) {
        if (status === "SUCCESS") {
            target.set("v.body", []);
            target.set('v.body', contentComponent);

            var newCmp = cmp.find('activeScreen');

            if (newCmp) {

               var info = newCmp.get("v.info"); // access attribute
               newCmp.loadData(data); // call component method

            } else {
               // newCmp is null
            }

        } else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
            console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
        } else if (status === "ERROR") {
            console.log(error);
            throw new Error(error);
        }
    });
},
```

Variable `newCmp` is always null.

But the component **does** load and display.

I need to call some methods and access some attributes in the component.

```
var info = newCmp.get("v.info"); // access attribute
newCmp.loadData(data); // call component method
```

How can I access the component after creating it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at least two potential problems.

## `body` Not Array

An attribute with `Aura.Component[]` always needs an array. Failure to do so may cause rendering issues. The fix is simple:

```
target.set('v.body', [contentComponent]);
```

## Not Yet Rendered

Setting the `body` attribute basically tells the system it needs to render (a part of) the DOM, but these actions are queued up until after your callback completes. As such, `component.find` can't find the component yet, because it's not part of the DOM.

Instead, just use the `contentComponent` directly:

```
if(contentComponent) {
  // Do stuff here
```

---

Edit: Based on chat room commentary:

The problem was assuming that the methods that were being called were needed. Instead, the attributes can be assigned during creation time:

```
$A.createComponent(name, {
    "aura:id": "activeScreen", "data": component.getReference("v.data")
}, function (contentComponent, status, error) {
```

This allows the component to handle loading its own data during init, removing the need for this particular question to begin with, since it was only needed to call `aura:method` functions to load the data post-initialization.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way for find out when the component has rendered, such that the rest of my code can access it?

Comment: @Robs You should be able to access the component any time after `afterRender` has fired in your component. You could [write a custom renderer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_renderers.htm) to know when the component is available. Honestly, though, I suspect your question may be an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). There should likely be a way to do what you're trying to do without resorting to a custom renderer. Maybe ask a question about what you're trying to do (the X) instead of a solution (the Y)?

Comment: I've added to the question. I would like to access attributes and call JavaScript methods on the component once it's loaded. The attributes are less important, because I have other ways to get that data, but I call the method and pass in data.

Comment: @Robs contentComponent gives you access to the component in the callback function. By the time your callback is called, contentComponent will have already processed its aura:valueInit handler, if any, so you should be able to access its attributes. Does that help?

Comment: RE your X-Y Problem comment, I'd like to ask you about the best approach to solve my problem, could we speak in a chat room, or would you prefer I asked a separate question?

Comment: @Robs I'd be glad to do a chat with you if you prefer, or you may ask a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78843/discussion-between-robs-and-sfdcfox).